# How to convert a char array with zero to int in java

Tags: java

I have a `char` array that starts with zeroes, but when I try to convert it to a `int` value, it deletes the zeroes, so I want to keep the zeroes as well.

Something like this array char contains 00001234 and the int has to be like this `00001234`, but when I use the `parseInt` it just leaves me 1234.

Answer (score 5):

An `int` contains a pure numeric value; there's no notion of representation like leading zeroes, thousands separators, etc. Anything like that is considered *formatting* -- it's only relevant when you need to display your `int` or convert it to text somehow. Facilities like `NumberFormat` or `System.out.printf()` give you some control over what formatting is applied, so that's what you'll have to use.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to use Java [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) if you want to keep leading zeros while printing.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot capture leading zeros in an int, or any numeric type. Leading zeros are irrelevant to the internal representation of a number, and are only useful when you're e.g. printing the number.

When you output the number, instead of printing an `int`, use a [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html), or a format `String` with [`System.out.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)/[`System.out.printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

If you must keep the number just as it was input, or as it is in your `char[]`, with the same number of leading zeros, you'll need to keep it around as a `char[]`, while doing numeric computations with the numeric equivalent from e.g. `parseInt`.

Answer (score 1):

int does not know about the formatting of the number, you will have to add the padding wherever the number is displayed

Answer (score 1):

You can't keep formatting stored in a simple int.  You just store the actual int number and then when you go to display it you use something like NumberFormat to pad it as desired.

Answer (score 0):

000001234 and 1234 are the same as integers. What you are looking for is the way to format (display the number) properly the integer and convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

see if [this](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/71046/how-use-integer-values-begins-with-zero) helps it has some suggestions on how to print numbers with leading zeroes, if you could tell the usage of these number a more relvant answer can be presented...